# Show Menubar in File Manager - XUbuntu

Tags: xubuntu, filemanager, menu-bar

I accidentally unchecked View -> Show Menubar which hides the menubar in File Manager, and there doesn't appear to be a keyboard shortcut to show the menubar again.
How can I go back and make it appear?

Comment: Maybe try ALT-V to pull up 'view' on the menu.  I had a look on Thunar (default file-manager on XFCE) and it reports ^M (ctrl+M) will return the menubar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look on Thunar (default file-manager on XFCE) and it reports ^M (ctrl+M) will display/hide the menu bar.

I had it visible so could look thru my menus, but if I didn't I'd have tried to hit ALT+V in hopes it'd show the VIEW menu (or ALT+F to show FILE menu).  It won't work in every program, desktop or place, but works for many.

Comment: this solves the problem!!

Comment: it says "wait 5 minutes more.."